# Should I use an interface when methods are only similar?

Tags: object-oriented-design, interfaces, abstraction

I was posed with the idea of creating an object that checks if a point will collide with a line:

```
public class PointAndLineSegmentCollisionDetector {
    public void Collides(Point p, LineSegment s) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This made me think that if I decided to create a **Box** object, then I would need a **PointAndBoxCollisionDetector** and a **LineSegmentAndBoxCollisionDetector**.  I might even realize that I should have a **BoxAndBoxCollisionDetector** and a **LineSegmentAndLineSegmentCollisionDetector**.  And, when I add new objects that can collide I would need to add even more of these.

But, they all have a **Collides** method, so everything I learned about abstraction is telling me, *"Make an interface."*

```
public interface CollisionDetector {
    public void Collides(Spatial s1, Spatial s2);
}
```

But now I have a function that only detects some abstract class or interface that is used by **Point**, **LineSegment**, **Box**, etc..  So if I did this then each implementation would have to to a type check to make sure that the types are the appropriate type because the collision algorithm is different for each different type match up.

Another solution could be this:

```
public class CollisionDetector {
    public void Collides(Point p, LineSegment s) { ... }
    public void Collides(LineSegment s, Box b) { ... }
    public void Collides(Point p, Box b) { ... }
    // ...
}
```

But, this could end up being a huge class that seems unwieldy, although it would have simplicity in that it is only a bunch of **Collide** methods.

This is similar to C#'s **Convert** class.  Which is nice because it is large, but it is simple to understand how it works.  This seems to be the better solution, but I thought I should open it for discussion as a wiki to get other opinions.

Comment: Most typical OO languages "dispatch" dynamically on one type only, so "dispatch on two types" is problematic, cumbersome, painful.

Comment: For the concrete problem of collision detection, you could look up what game engines do, such as Ogre or Irrlicht (source code), or Unreal or CryEngine (API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic interface would fit well here

```
public interface ICollisionDetector<TFirst, TSecond>
{
    bool Collides(TFirst first, TSecond second);
}

public class PointAndBoxCollisionDetector : ICollisionDetector<Point, Box>
{
    public bool Collides(Point first, Box second)
    {
        // Collision logic
    }
}
```

You can use a FactoryMethod to generate your detector, based on the types of the two objects you have.

```
public class CollisionDetectorFactory
{
    public ICollisionDetector<TFirst, TSecond> Create<TFirst, TSecond>()
    {
         // Here you can have a giant switch/case, or 
         // you can map using reflection, or you can get
         // from an IoC Container/Service Locator.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you extend the answer to show what using reflection and using an IoC Container/Service locator would look like?

Answer (score 3):

### Theory

One should implement a common interface when:

- Objects are similar and have a similar logic, **and:**
- The shared logic is used in other places where the distinction between the types is not required.

For example, one shouldn't implement a common interface for both `Dog: Animal` and `RSS`, just because both have a common method `Feed`. Not only the logic behind those two methods is different (`new Dog(...).Feed()` would launch a robot which will give some food to a dog, while `new RSS(...).Feed()` will simply download the most recent RSS from the server), but you can hardly imagine a common `Feeder` which would be responsible of controlling dog food *and* downloading the last RSS feeds.

On the other hand, it would be convenient to have a common interface for both `new Dog(...).Feed()` and `new Goldfish(...).Feed()`, because while the implementation would be different, since the robot is expected to not putting a bowl of meat into an aquarium, the common interface still allows for the callers to not make any difference between the animals:

```
var myPets = new [] { (IAnimal)new Dog(...), new Goldfish(...) };
...
new FeedingEngine().FeedPets(myPets);

public class FeedingEngine
{
    public void FeedPets(IEnumerable<IAnimal> pets)
    {
        foreach (var pet in pets)
        {
            if (pet.Status == AnimalStatus.Alive && pet.IsPotentiallyHungry)
            {
                pet.Feed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Your case

Both of your proposals are correct. From the point of view of the consumer of `ICollisionDetector`, all I need to know is that I can pass any pair of spacial objects and get the collision result, no matter how.

There is a slight difference between those approaches: it's the fact that the first proposal requires you to double-check if **all** objects inheriting `ISpatial` are handled correctly by the collision detector. It can be error prone later: if, working on your code later, another developer implements another spatial object, let's say `Sphere: ISpatial`, but forgets to implement the collision logic, `Collides(sphere, box)` will fail, and it would be difficult to understand why is it failing, especially if the collision detector is used indirectly, like through the game engine.

The second approach is an opt-in. If the collision detector doesn't have a `Collides(Sphere s, Box b)`, nobody would be able to call such a conversion. This being said, this itself creates another problem: you will not be able to use generics or any high-level abstraction. For example:

```
var box = new Box(...);
var torus = new Torus(...);

var engine = new GameEngine();
engine.Show(new [] { box, torus });
engine.StartColliding(); // Moves objects to the center of the map and stops on collision.
```

is easy to implement with your first proposal if both `Box` and `Torus` implement `ISpatial`, but would be extremely difficult to do with your second proposal.

In order to be able to use your first proposal while reducing the issue I noted above, here's a third proposal:

```
public interface ISpatial
{
    bool IsColliding(ISpatial obj);
}

public class CollisionDetector
{
    public bool IsColliding(ISpatial s1, ISpatial s2)
    {
        return s1.IsColliding(s2);
    }
}

public class Torus : ISpatial
{
    public bool IsColliding(ISpatial obj)
    {
        // Check that obj is not null.

        // Do the collision logic for known types.
        var box = obj as Box;
        if (box != null)
        {
            // Do the collision logic.
            return result;
        }

        return obj.IsColliding(this);
    }
}

public class Cube : ISpatial
{
    public bool IsColliding(ISpatial obj)
    {
        // Check that obj is not null.

        // Do the collision logic for known types.

        return obj.IsColliding(this);
    }
}
```

Since the cube class is created first, it is unaware of torus; instead of throwing a `NotImplementedException`, it simply delegates the collision detection logic to the torus, which is well aware of the cube object, since the torus class was the second one to be created.

Note: of course, you still have to handle the situations where neither the first, nor the second object are aware of each other (for example if two objects were created by two different developers at the same moment of time). Actual code above will simply overflow and crash, but you can easily change it to throw `NotImplementedException` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Programmingly speaking**, pdr's solution offers the best design but I would have suggested first to use an IoC container (configured to return single instances), then using reflection if not possible and really lastly using a switch/case.

Now **mathematically speaking**, I think there are maybe more optimal solutions to this problem.
For example, if your goal is really to just detect the collision between several objects in motion an be able to resolve theses collisions, for example in a game like 'angry birds', there are many optimal algorithms.

I'd suggest that maybe you should expose the problem you are trying to solve on  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
Since for me it's more a math/physics programming problem than a 'pure' programming problem.

It would be a shame to design a complex Object Oriented solution whilst there is maybe a simpler (and with better performance) mathematical solution.

Comment: Agreed.  That will help when I am actually working on this, but this was the best example I had to ask the question about interfaces.  Could you explain why you think an IoC container would be better?

Comment: Using a IoC container will save you the time to write all the reflection code to fetch all the concrete implementations, plus IoC container offers out of the box instance life time strategies. By using an IoC container, you will respect the Open Closed principle. This mean that any time you will need a new type of Collision Detection, you will just have to write the new implementation without having to touch any existing code. If you don't use an IoC container and use a "big switch/case", any time you add a new type of Collision detection, you will have to update that big switch/case.